# Perl : How to remove white spaces in beginning of each line of a file?

Tags: perl

I have written this code but it is not working..The white spaces still exist

```
open(FILE2, "<WordNetTest2.txt");
my @lin=<FILE2>;
while (<FILE2>) {
    s/\^\s+//g;
}
print FILE2 "@lin";
close(FILE2);
```

Comment: `\^` is wrong. that turns it itnto a caret literal, and it will no longer be treated as "start of string". You're telling the regex to look for a literal `^` in the text, followed by one or more whitespace characters.

Comment: @MarcB you should submit that as an answer.

Comment: My Perl is a bit rusty, but doesn't `@lin=<FILE2>` slurp up the whole file into array `@lin`, leaving the filehandle positioned at EOF?  Even if it didn't, you then loop over lines in the file, performing your substitution on each line, and discarding the results.

Comment: ok right  so should it be like   s/^\s+//g ..but i tried rightaway . this is also not working

Comment: how can i make it work?

Comment: Is there any other mistake I'v done in the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- 3 argument open is much better.
- you should really check return codes of `open`.
- Assigning a file to an array reads the whole file. This is redundant in your case, and wastes memory (which is a consideration for larger files).
- but when you do this, the while loop right after has nothing to read.
- You're opening a file to read, which means it isn't open for writing.
- your regex is broken. Escaping `\^` makes it literal. Try `s/\A\s+//` or `w/^\s+//` which will match start of line.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings; 

open ( my $input, "<", "WordNetTest2.txt" ) or die $!; 
open ( my $output, ">", "WordNetTest2NEW.txt" ) or die $!; 

while ( my $line = <$input> ) {
   $line =~ s/^\s+//;
   print {$output} $line;
}

close ( $input );
close ( $output );

#copy one over the other if so inclined
```

However, your problem may be solved even more simply with `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/^ +//g' WordNetTest2.txt
```

Comment: thankyou so much Sobrique for pointing out my mistakes..i got it now!! One more thing when you write die $! , die is used to display error messages right ...what does $! mean?

Comment: $! means 'the error generated by open' (in this case). So if your file isn't readable, it'll tell you that's why it wouldn't work. (Test it by `chmod a-r` on your file if you like)

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code.

You open the filehandle for reading (better would be the three-argument-version of `open` with lexical filehandle and error checking `open my $fh , '<' , 'file.txt' or die "Cannot read file.txt: $!\n";`). Then you read in the complete file in the array `@lin` leaving the filehandle at EOF. Therefor the while loop has nothing to do.
Now you try to print the unmodified array to a readonly filehandle and then close the filehandle.

Better would be:

```
use strict ;
use warnings ;

my $filename = 'WordNetTest2.txt' ;
open my $fh , '<' , $filename or die "Cannot read '$filename': $!\n" ;
my @lines = <$fh> ;
close $fh ;

for ( @lines ) {
  s/^\s+// ; # No need for global substitution
}

open $fh , '>' , $filename or die "Cannot write '$filename': $!\n" ;
print $fh @lines ;
close $fh ;
```

Comment: thankyou so mch for pointing out my mistakes!! working now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
perl -i -pe 's/^\s+//' WordNetTest2.txt
```

Comment: Whilst correct, I think your answer would benefit from a bit more explanation as to what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You've escaped your caret:

```
s/\^\s+//g;
  ^--
```

which means it's no longer the "start of string" regex metachar. it's become a literal caret, meaning:

```
foo^  bar      <--matches
foo   bar      <--no match, because no caret
```

Answer (score 0):

Is very easy:

```
open(FILE2, "< WordNetTest2.txt");
my @lin=< FILE2>;
$str_file = join("", @lin);
print FILE2 "$str_file";
close(FILE2);
```

It worked for me.